# Matlab-How to perform logical AND operation in single matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, logical-operators

Hi I have 4x4 matrix which need to perform AND operations in 2x2,3x3 and 4x4. How to perform it in matlab.

I have tried this code.

```
 R2=and(var(1,:),var(2,:))
```

R2 =

```
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     0     1
 1     0     1     0
 1     1     0     0
```

First  2x2 ans is 1 1
second 3x3 ans is 1 0 0
last   4x4 ans is 1 0 0 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all() checks if none of the elements of the vector are zero. On matrizes it returns the vector of hte first non-singleton dimension so you have to do it twice.

```
for i=2:4
    all( all(R2(1:i,1:i)) )
end
```